# jna/c#: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'Test'

Tags: java, c#, jna

I would like to use a C# dll function.

c#

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace dllExample
{
    public class DllExample
    {
        [RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]
        public static string Test(string id)
        {
            return "done" + id;
        }
    }
}
```

java

```
@Test
public void jnaTest() {
    DllExample dllExample = Native.loadLibrary("c:\\Users\\IEUser\\RiderProjects\\dllExample\\dllExample\\bin\\Release\\RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata.dll", DllExample.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("doneabc", dllExample.Test("abc"));
}

public interface DllExample extends Library{
    String Test(String id);
}
```

I build the c# project with Visual Studio and it makes 3 files into the project bin\Release directory:

- dllExample.dll
- dllExample.pdb
- RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata.dll

JDK version: 1.8.171

jna: net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.5.1

When the test is run, I get this exception:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'Test': A
>   megadott eljárás nem található.
>
> at com.sun.jna.Function.(Function.java:245)   at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:566)     at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:542)     at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:528)     at
>   com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:228)  at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.Test(Unknown Source)    at
>   hu.kdiv.keaesz.sign.DirectMSCAPITest.jnaTest(DirectMSCAPITest.java:149)

What do I miss?
I was build the dll with Visual Studio Build Solution function.

Answer (score 0):

I was UnmanagedExpirt NuGet package. It is not good.

Solution:

Delete UnmanagedExport and use DllExport NuGet package. Description here: https://github.com/3F/DllExport